# mongoDB - Linux Service Startup/Shutdown is Failing (possible unclean shutdown)

Tags: linux, mongodb, init.d

Linux administration isn't my thing so I'm a bit over my head here.

System information:

/proc/version -> Linux version 2.6.18-028stab091.2

/etc/debian_version -> 5.0.8

Whenever the server is shutdown & restarted, MongoDB isn't coming up.  It looks like mongod isn't shutting down cleanly.  The .lock file is still present & I can't bring it up manually until I remove this and run a --repair.  If I look in mongod's log file I don't see the shutdown sequence, it just goes from a query to the startup.

```
Wed Jul 13 17:57:49 [conn1] update ps.profiles  query: { blah blah blah } 224ms
Thu Jul 14 07:07:51 MongoDB starting : pid=1167 port=27017 dbpath=/srv/db/ProfileServer 64-bit
```

I can see that the scripts are in place to handle shutdown & restart:

```
$ ls -l /etc/rc0.d/*mongodb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Feb 17 09:46 /etc/rc0.d/K20mongodb -> ../init.d/mongodb
$ ls -l /etc/rc2.d/*mongodb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Feb 17 09:46 /etc/rc2.d/S20mongodb -> ../init.d/mongodb
$ ls -l /etc/rc6.d/*mongodb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Feb 17 09:46 /etc/rc6.d/K20mongodb -> ../init.d/mongodb
```

I know that the scripts work.  By running

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb start
```

I see in the logs

```
... various other shutdown messages ...
Thu Jul 14 08:42:06 [interruptThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Jul 14 08:42:06 dbexit: really exiting now
Thu Jul 14 08:42:12 MongoDB starting : pid=3184 port=27017 dbpath=/srv/db/ProfileServer 64-bit
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?  Is there any log file that will let me trace through the runlevel change?

Comment: Is that a typo `.../mongod start` (or `../init.d/mongodb`), or does the symlink in `/etc/rcX.d` really point to a different file in `/etc/init.d` ?

Comment: Typo, I've corrected it.

Comment: Is the a KXX script, where XX < 20 that would prevent mongodb from shutting down properly?

Comment: @embobo raises a very good point - on my system here, filesystems are unmounted around `K09`, so by the time a `K20` script is reached the FS would be gone.  Try moving your `K20mongodb` to around `K05mongodb`.

Comment: K11atd is the only one <20.  The unmount scripts are S40 and S60

Comment: Did you install this from a deb package? Which version?

Comment: On Debian squeeze, `dpkg-query -l mongodb-server` reveals I have version 1:1.4.4-3, which is the standard squeeze release version. Mine fails on boot also, and works if I hand-start it by `sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb restart`. There seems to be nothing directly about this in Debian [bugs](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?archive=both;dist=stable;package=mongodb-server;package=mongodb).

Comment: On boot, sometimes the latest squeeze backports package (1:2.0.0-2~bpo60+1) starts okay, sometimes it seems to fail. However (astonishingly), even with the message, 'Starting database: mongodb failed!', the database is working, evidenced by `$ mongo` and `> show dbs`.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully had this work using the packaged versions from the 10gen repos:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CentOS+and+Fedora+Packages

I suspect the issue here is how the shutdown is happening and how long it waits to kill the mongo process.  If you don't want to go to the bother of installing a package just to look at some init scripts, head over to github and check out the source (one of the advantages of an open source DB :))

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/rpm/init.d-mongod

Compare and contrast with your own init scripts and set up to see where things might have gone wrong.